# Strongest shadow

Tags: rendering, node-editor, shaders

Blender Cycles. I have lamp type sun and i want have strongest shadow (blacker) but emission must stay. I have sun "size" = 0 and still not strong for me. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to lower the brightness of the background, which creates the ambient light, illuminating the scene evenly.

Go to the **World** tab and change the **Color** value of the **Surface** panel to black.

[image: World Panel]

Comment: Yes sure but i cant change background surface color, because i have to dark scene then. Can other idea?

Comment: Can you share a picture of how your scene should look like vs how it looks now?